Problem trying to load zip extension for php 7 on Ubuntu 22.04
I am trying to load zip.so for an older version of php (7.033) and I am getting the error message "undefined symbol: pcre_exec is unknown". I installed using sudo apt-get install php7.0-zip after doing an update. I originally installed php to /usr/local after doing a custom build when I could not find the package, other extensions have loaded without issue (although it took some work to get xdebug to work). Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
I have tried manually moving the zip.so file into the extensions folder. That is when I get the error above. I modified the php.ini file and have restarted apache multiple times. I also verified that pcre is loaded by running php -m

"I modified the php.ini file" - which ini file, and is it actually in use?  You mention running php -m, that's the PHP CLI and uses a different php.ini than the one Apache uses.  You also mention restarting Apache - are you updating/checking both ini files?

When you use apt-get to install PHP extensions, the package already contains the appropriate configuration in individual *.ini files. If you edit configuration files manually to add or remove extensions, you're interfering with this. And if you mix pre-built binary packages and custom compilations you're bypassing dependency management. You need to clean up all your previous fiddling so packages can work as expected.

The extension you're trying to load may have been compiled with a different API version. Are you running the same php and php-fpm versions? They have to be the same.
